# Stop wrapping contained divs?

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow, css-float

I currently have a setup of divs within a container div, as follows:

```
<div id="container">  
    <div id="element"> Element 1 content </div>  
    <div id="element"> Element 2 content </div>  
    <div id="element"> Element 3 content </div>  
    <div id="element"> Element 4 content </div>  
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.container {
width:200px;
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
}  

.element {
width:100px;
float:left;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vZWTc/.

So, I would like each of the elements to line up next to each other (all 4 in one row), but only have the first two visible (container is 200px, each element is 100px, so only 2 are visible at a time), while the user can scroll (horizontally) to the 3rd and 4th elements (as they are less important)

However, with this setup, elements 3 and 4 wrap down to the next line

updating the container class with `white-space:nowrap` does nothing. That only affects text, not divs apparently.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your fiddle uses .element instead of #element so it doesn't work. Can you fix up please?

Comment: Han's answer looks like the best one to me. Fiddle is here. Nobody else got the horizontal scrolling that you want. 

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/vZWTc/1/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a wrapper div with the total width of the 4 elements, and set the container to hidden overflow, html example...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element"> Element 1 content </div>
    <div class="element"> Element 2 content </div>
    <div class="element"> Element 3 content </div>
    <div class="element"> Element 4 content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for the css

```
.container { width:200px; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; }
.wrapper { width: 400px; }
.element { width:100px; float:left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods:

1) Clearfix - added to the container.

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

2) Clearing DIV - placed after the last floating element.

```
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear {
   clear:both;
   font-size:0;
}
```

You can save some markup in your situation be using an unordered list instead:

```
<ul id="container">  
    <li> Element 1 content </li>  
    <li> Element 2 content </li>  
    <li> Element 3 content </li>  
    <li> Element 4 content </li>  
</ul>
```

This way you can style the contents without and extra class name. It makes more semantic sense as well.

```
.container li {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Divs are block level elements - which means they create a new line. If you want block level elements next to eachother then they will need to be floated with `float:left` or `float:right`. Remember to clear them with `clear: both` when you want stuff to start going onto new lines.

To prevent them from wrapping you can use the `overflow:` parameter.

I would also suggest using the CSS direct child selector instead of specifying the same class 
`element` over and over again. `div.container > div { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can just set height: [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/Ech2t/)

```
.container { width:200px; height:20px; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; }
.element { width:100px; height:20px;  float:left; }


<div class="container">
<div class="element"> Element 1 content </div>
<div class="element"> Element 2 content </div>
<div class="element"> Element 3 content </div>
<div class="element"> Element 4 content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly for these fields to use those CSS styles - they would need to be #container and #element respectively. Either that or change it to use a wrapping div to handle the scrolling.

**Markup:**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="wrappingcontainer">
    <div class="element"> Element 1 content </div>
    <div class="element"> Element 2 content </div>
    <div class="element"> Element 3 content </div>
    <div class="element"> Element 4 content </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #container { width:200px; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; }
   .element { width:100px; float:left; }
   .wrappingcontainer{ width: 400px; }
```

[Demo available here!](http://jsfiddle.net/Ech2t/1/)